# Split string inside string in C# using regular expressions

Tags: c#, regex

I have a string similar to 
**SOI;** 1; 2; 3; 4; 5;  6; 7; **SOI;** 8; 9; 10; 11; 12; **EOI;** 13; **EOI; SOI;** 14; 15; 16; 17; 18; **EOI;**

Here i have to split the string starting from SOI; to EOI; 
The output should be like

[0] - 1; 2; 3; 4; 5; 6; 7; 13;
[1] - 8; 9; 10; 11; 12; 
[2] - 14; 15; 16; 17; 18;

I have tried to split using the below code

```
string regexexpr = "(?s)(?<=SOI;).+?(?=EOI;)";//@"SOI;(.*?)EOI;";
string sText = "SOI; 1; 2; 3; 4; 5;  6; 7;SOI; 8; 9; 10; 11; 12; EOI; 13; EOI; SOI; 14; 15; 16; 17; 18; EOI;";
MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(sText, @regexexpr);
var sample = matches.Cast<Match>().Select(m => m.Value);
```

But i am getting output like
[0] - 1; 2; 3; 4; 5; 6; 7; **SOI;** 8; 9; 10; 11; 12;
[1] - 14; 15; 16; 17; 18;

Please provide me with a better solution.
Thanks

Comment: Are you asking how to extract nested SOI/EOI structures? I'd be surprised if you can do that with regular expressions. It would be easier to write code to process the list of values

Comment: Wait, How do you expect `[0] - 1; 2; 3; 4; 5; 6; 7; 13;` as output? Where does that 13 come from when `8; 9; 10; 11; 12; ` goes to next match?

Answer (score 0):

I think I'd do it procedurally, instead of using a regexp.

EDIT: The following solution has a mistake, first and third list would be the same. I'm leaving it because it may still be a hint in the right direction.

1)Set a Value to zero.
2)Read next token in the string.
3)If token is SOI, add 1 to Value
4)If token is EOI, remove 1 from Value
5)If token is a number, add it to a different array (or list) depending on Value.
6)GOTO 2

Answer (score 0):

```
    private static List<string> GetLists(string sText)
    {
        string[] output;
        List<string> input = new List<string>();
        input = sText.Split(new string[] {" "}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToList();
        int count = input.Count(x => x == "SOI;");
        output = new string[count]; // set output array to number of lists in string
        int current = -1;  // start with -1 so first SOI will set it on 0
        int max = -1;
        foreach (var text in input)
        {
            if (text == "SOI;") // set current and max
            {
                current++;
                max++;
            }
            else if (text == "EOI;")
            {
                current--;
                if (current == -1)  // if u reached -1 it means u are out of any list so set current on max so if u will get "SOI" u will get proper number
                {
                    current = max;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                output[current] += text;
            }
        }

        return output.ToList();
    }
}
```